# Modeling within subjects

Tags: anova, t-test

I am having a bit of a statistics problem, and thought I would throw it to the internet before I bash my head in.

Participants were shown stimuli and asked a question while EEG was recorded. The stimulus and question varied in two ways over two levels each: medium (video/text) and content (physics/social).

Each participant was presented with four trials of each of the four types in random order. Between each block of four trials was a fixation period that could be used as a control (although that may not be necessary).

The outcome variable was EEG spectral power at three separate electrodes. The activity between the electrodes is likely to be highly correlated.

I am primarily trying to find the effect of the content (physics/social) manipulation.

What analysis would you suggest to model this design?

Comment: Please give us more detail, tell us your real problem. Then maybe we can help!

Comment: Looks like part of my problem is that I don't know how to articulate what I need! I essentially want to discover if there is a significant effect of the manipulation (the two levels). I have tried a paired t-test on the participant means of each level, but this collapses eight readings into one, which I assume is counter-productive. Is this the information required?

Comment: To help you to articulate, we need to know your real problem! That is, tell us what is the problem about, not how you think it should be translated into math/stat language. We can do that translation, if you tell us the  real problem.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Kjetil. I have edited the question to contain the long version!

Answer (score 0):

Following may be helpful:

Your data can have following columns:

```
subjectId physics_social pre_post eeg_level
1  physics  pre  10
1  physics  post 15
1  social   pre  12
1  social   post 11
2...
```

Pre will be the control level. The medium is ignored here. Then ANOVA repeated measures can be applied (following is code in R):

```
aov(eeg_level ~ physics_social * pre_post + Error(subjectID/pre_post), data=yourdata)
```

Situation similar to yours in described on: http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/repeated.html  (see chicken-pasta example).

Another site with good explanation for pre-post data with repeated measures: http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/pre-post-data-repeated-measures/

For coding ANOVA with different parameters in R: http://www.statmethods.net/stATS/anova.html

I myself struggled with similar questions and found that expert do not agree on the best approach. Other alternatives are:

t-test between post eeg_level values of physics vs social groups (ignoring the pre values)

t-test between pre-post difference in eeg_level values of physics vs social groups.

linear modelling:

```
lm(eeg_level~ physics_social+pre_post, data=mydata)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! Would there be a way using a similar technique to compare directly between the physics and social conditions? Also can this technique accommodate the multiple readings from each condition for each participant?

Comment: I have added another link in the answer which is likely to be helpful for this.

Comment: Thanks rsno, that helps a lot. I think the main problem is that I will find it problematic to use a pre-post design, because the control condition is not visually or attentionally equivalent to the physics/social conditions. 

I was hoping to compare the two conditions directly, but because of the random order it is not straightforward to match the trials from the two for a paired t-test.

What I essentially need is a t-test for each participant between conditions, then to combine the t-scores for all participants. Does such a technique exist?

Comment: What is the problem with unpaired t-test in this situation? I do not think there is any statistical test for comparing a participant's one score to same participant's another score. You always compare 2 groups, which may or may not be paired.